# Why do we use canvas.save or canvas.restore?

Tags: android

I know what it does. If I dont use sometimes I can see the difference in alignments, sometimes I don't. My question is: if `canvas.restore` restores the state previous to when it was saved, why aren't the changes made after save and before restore undone? The changes remain. Why?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`canvas.save` and `canvas.restore` undo things like rotation and translation. They don't undo drawing on the canvas. The android canvas works similarly to the HTML5 canvas, so you can look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations if you need more clarification.