# Android: How to rotate drawRect or drawText in canvas without rotate other components of Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, google-maps-api-3, rotation

I am using canvas on mapview for custom marker I have draw multiple components in Canvas but I want to rotate only one component rotate not all the components rotate same time. canvas have his own builtin function `canvas.rotate(degree);` but when we sub components like `canvas.drawRect`, `canvas.drawText` or `canvas.drawBitmap` then how we use rotate drawRect.
sorry for bad english...
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can save `Canas` state and then restore its state to remove all modifications:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(degree);
canvas.drawText(...);
canvas.restore();
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29040892/1432752) answer you can read more about point of managing cavas state.